Apposition with Auxiliary Verbs
In the sentence "She had done it, eaten the cake" the participle phrase "eaten the cake" seems to be in an appositive relation with the pronoun "it." But if we swap in the one for the other we get the obviously ungrammatical "She had done eaten the cake."
Likewise, if we do the swapping with "He did what she told him to, ran home" then we get "He did ran home."
What is the explanation for this apparent discrepancy? Thank you!

'Done it' and 'eaten the cake' are in what some would call apposition (and others wouldn't).

"A seems to apposite B" doesn't work for me. Are you sure you're using "apposite" as a verb here?

I don’t know what to call them, but they aren’t appositives. Read like this: She had done it: [She had] eaten the cake. / He did what she told him to: [He] ran home. / He did what she told him to: [She told him to] run home.

It looks like a compound predicate but with a comma (or a dash) replacing say [and]. Some call all such 'interchangeable' strings appositives, as with the explanatory synonym (adjective)  'the contents are recondite (abstruse)'.

[But if we swap one for the other we get the obviously ungrammatical "She had done eaten the cake."] "She had done it, [she had] eaten the cake." It's just an ellipsis. She had done it, she had eaten the cake.

This seems to be a right dislocation. DOn't have time to check up on it, but maybe someone else will.

@Araucaria-Him Nothing has been moved. Something has been left out.

I think an apposition would be "eating the cake". The gerund makes it a noun phrase, which can replace the pronoun.

@Lambie I don't understand your comment. Do you misunderstand what a right dislocation is?

@Araucaria-Him On Wikipedia, the example given is: They went to the store, Mary and Peter. That is not this: "She had done it, eaten the cake". That is: "She had done it, [she had] eaten the cake"

It seems to be a case of someone hesitating and clarifying their previous comment with a grammatically-unconnected phrase. It's very common for people to do this.


What is the explanation for this apparent discrepancy? Thank you!


"She had done it, eaten the cake" the participle phrase "eaten the cake" seems to be in an appositive relation with the pronoun "it." But if we swap in the one for the other we get the obviously ungrammatical "She had done eaten the cake."

No we don't. We get "She had eaten the cake"
"Done" is acing as a "pro-verb" - it is cataphoric to "eaten".

Likewise, if we do the swapping with "He did what she told him to, ran home" then we get "He did ran run home." / "He ran home"

No we don't. We get "He ran home"
"Did" in the example = to perform an/the action. the action is then specified by "he ran home.
She told him to run home and he ran home.
For the complete apposition the full verb clause has to be repeated. This is no different from noun clauses in apposition.
